transformation from cartesian coordinate to spherical
Suppose I have a vector  $A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$ in $x,y,z$ standard coordinate  and I want to find the corrispective vector when I use spherical  coordinates $A_r,A_\theta,A_{\varphi}$
I know that in general I have to write:
$$\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{l}
A_r \\
A_\theta \\
A_{\varphi}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin \theta \cos \varphi & \sin \theta \sin \varphi & \cos \theta \\
\cos \theta \cos \varphi & \cos \theta \sin \varphi & -\sin \theta \\
-\sin \varphi & \cos \varphi & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
A_x \\
A_y \\
A_z
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}$$
but my question is why do I  have to use a matrix  the transformation from standard coordinate to spherical coordinate is not linear so why it is used ths matrix ? I think I might have found the answer and use geometry, but I haven't seen for a long period so I don't know if it is valid or not:
prop: If V is a vector space  and has basis $B$ and $C$ then $[v]_B=M[v]_C$ where v is a vector and the notation        [v]_B are the coordinate of the vector in that base   and M is the matrix of changing coordinates.
Could this be right ?

Why do you think the transformation is not linear? Could you try to use definition to verify this?

In short: $(A_x,A_y,A_z)$ are the components of the vector
$$
\mathbf{A}=A_x,\hat{\mathbf x}+A_y,\hat{\mathbf y}+A_z,\hat{\mathbf z}
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf x},\hat{\mathbf y},\hat{\mathbf z}$ are the Cartesian basis vectors. To transform those components you want that matrix because $\mathbf{A}$ has to be equal to
$$
\mathbf{A}=A_r,\hat{\mathbf r}+A_\theta,\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}+A_\varphi,\hat{\boldsymbol \varphi},.
$$
